# Python: Connecting to a private page using urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to connect to a private page were you have to be logged in to view it using urllib. When I try to connect to the page I just get redirected, to the login page.
Is there a way to log in with urllib or use cookies from my webrowser or something like that?
I have tried to figure out how to do it myself and have failed.
Any help on this would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

If your page uses HTML authentication, use [`HTTPBasicAuthHandler`](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html).

If your page uses authentication by form, use POST request to send login form and store the cookies using [`cookielib`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look for Authentication under http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples